# Public Bool Get Set Statement

Tags: boolean

By all means this statement should work, but returns and error when I compile?  Thoughts?

```
public bool sheetCreatorSave {
    get {
        return (bool)this["sheetCreatorSave"];
    }
    set {
        this["sheetCreatorSave"] = (object)(bool)(value ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: What language is this in? Please add some more tags.

Comment: The language is 'C' sharp

Comment: - and what's the error?

Comment: Cannot convert type 'int' to 'bool'

Comment: Oh, right, that's the `value ?` bit. So instead of `(bool)(value ? 1 : 0)` simply do `value`.